# Building a dynamic menu based on taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, routes

I'm new to Drupal and I am currently using Drupal 7. I need to know if what I am trying to do is even possible. If so I am going to need some pointers on how to implement it.

I have two vocabularies: *Category* and *Brand*. I have products that are tagged with a brand and one or more categories. I want a mega menu, dynamically built based on these terms. Basically, if there is a product tagged with category "A" and brand "X", a link should be created in the menu under products. So the menu would look like *Products >> A >> X*. Is there a way to accomplish this? I was thinking that I could create a custom module that would find all nodes of type product and create a category link for each new category it finds; then create a brand under the proper category.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Taxonomy Menu module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Transforms your taxonomy vocabularies into menus with ease!
>
> Features
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with Views
> - Integrate with Pathauto: use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

I found these tutorials helpful to get started.

[First](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCwD-qVS2a0) Tutorial (youtube video).

[Second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAWyw0GU49E) Tutorial (youtube video).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion but I don't think Taxonomy Menu will accomplish what I need. Category and Brand are 2 separate vocabularies and the Brands need to be sub-menus of Category. Also I am not linking to the actual taxonomy term page I have created a views pages for the catalog listing. so if you are on www.example.com/products/categoryX/brandY you will see a list of all products tagged with categoryX and brandY pulled from the URL. And what I would like to accomplish is dynamically building the menu link to each brand based on nodes tagged with a certain category/brand combination

Answer (score 1):

If you need a cross Vocabularies like Product >> Cat-A >> Brand-X then you can use Taxonomi Menu UI (https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_ui).

Taxonomy Menu UI works like "Node-Menu Setting", mean you can:

- Choose any parents: Brand-X has parent of Cat-A as your example
- Only show/hide certain Term on menu